# Configure Query Router Instances

Tags: mongodb

I have wrote this command

```
mongos --bind_ip 0.0.0.0 --configdb config0/server1:27017,server2:27017
```

It is working for all things.
But when I close this terminal then mongos connection is not working.
**How can I keep this connection permanently?**

Comment: What O/S are you using? On Linux or macOS you can include the [`--fork`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongos/#cmdoption-mongos-fork) option to run `mongos` as a daemon/background process. If you want to run `mongos` persistently you could set up a service definition, but the steps will depend on your O/S and version.

Comment: My O/S is Ubuntu

Comment: --fork is working @Stennie